# JPA Criteria Query for Left joins

Tags: java, jpa, criteriaquery

I am new to JPA and I have a Left Join scenario.
I have my native sql query as below and I am using left join to fetch the complete records from V_MONITORING table for st.id = 10001.
I have some null values for id_legislature which also needs to be selected and hence using a left join

```
select distinct 
    mv.id_set, mv.id_travel, mv.id_legislature
from 
   V_MONITORING mv 
     left join v_set st on mv.id_set = st.id
     left join v_travel fg on mv.id_travel = fg.id
     left join v_legislature gg on mv.id_legislature = gg.id;
```

The same thing I am implementing using the JPA criteria query, I am unable to fetch the null records 
Below is the code

```
Predicate predicate = cb.conjunction();
Root<MonitoringBE> mvRoot = criteriaQuery.from(MonitoringBE.class); 
mvRoot.fetch(MonitoringBE.id_set, JoinType.LEFT);
mvRoot.fetch(MonitoringBE.id_travel, JoinType.LEFT);
mvRoot.fetch(MonitoringBE.id_legislature, JoinType.LEFT);

final Path<Object> serieneinsatzterminPath= mvRoot.get(MonitoringBE.id_set);
predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.EqualTo(serieneinsatzterminPath.get(SetBE.GUELTIG_VON_DATUM), startSetDate));

criteriaQuery.multiselect(
   mvRoot.get(MonitoringBE.id_travel).alias("id_travel"),
   mvRoot.get(MonitoringBE.id_set).alias("id_set"),
   mvRoot.get(MonitoringBE.id_legislature).alias("id_legislature"))
.distinct(true).where(predicate);
```

Can some one guide me.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what behaviour your observe and how it is different from what you expect?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the `mvRoot.get(MonitoringBE.id_travel)` and others in the multiselect-statement with `mvRoot.join(MonitoringBE.id_travel, JoinType.LEFT)`. Otherwise they will end up in a inner join.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin, it work perfectly. Thank you so so much.